# Parsing XML file on SD card with Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm running myself around in circles here and the answer should be so simple. I have an XML file downloaded to my phone and saved to SD card. The format is simply...

```
<programmes>
    <programme>
        <title>Tom and Jerry</title>
        <description>Cat and mouse capers</description>
        <start_time>...</start_time>
    </programme>
    <programme>
        ...
    </programme>
</programmes>
```

Essentially all I want to do is retrieve all `<programme>` elements and parse the internal data which will be used to create a SQL INSERT command to populate a SQLite db.

I've tried with DOM but using Document.parse() took me out of memory (the xml file is 3.5MB in size). I've never worked with SAX and can't find an example that makes sense for my idea of how I want to do things and although I've used XPATH, again I can't find any example using the available android apis.

As I said, I'm sure this is easy and it's just my approach is wrong so I'd appreciate any pointers to doing this.

Comment: You've looked at the [javax.xml.xpath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) package?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't find any good example code for using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) details all three methods of XML parsing available on Android: DOM, SAX and pull parser. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had actually seen that article but it confused me even more. It's probably not good to do these things at 5am as I was yesterday. ;-) I took a fresh look at the article and adapted the AndroidSaxFeedParser example and associated code to use a FileInputStream to generate a List<Programme> result. Looking good so far - thanks for making me read it again. :D